# Blinking Cursor when trying to run live Ubuntu 13.10 on USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, 13.10, vaio

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on this laptop forever. I have my USB drive all setup and ready to go, but when I try booting from my flash drive it just shows a blank screen with a blinking cursor. I can't even get to the screen where it asks you to either try or to install Ubuntu.

I have tested this USB with other computers and it works with them but not this one. It is a Sony Vaio VGN-FE550G(PCG-7H1L) and it uses an old Phoenix BIOS. And no it isn't the Phoenix Awards BIOS,it is just the Phoenix BIOS. IF anyone can help me I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the BIOS of your computer, you can set the USB stick as a boot device. In some BIOS' they prefer to refer to the thumbdrive as a USB Removable Floppy Disk or USB Zip Disk.

GENERIC PHOENIX BIOS (May vary)

1. Go to "Advanced BIOS Features".
2. Go to the "1st Boot device" and set it to "USB-ZIP". Sometimes the device is listed as a USB hard drive under the hard drives menu.
3. Reboot

If you don't see the USB device as an option in the boot device order screen then it is probably not supported with your current BIOS version. If your PC's BIOS does not seem to support this, check if there is a BIOS update available.

Comment: That's the thing, it does boot the usb but all it brings me to is a blinking cursor.

Comment: It sounds like something could have gone wrong when making it initially. The blank screen and blinking cursor indicate there's no boot data/table to read on the disks or The BIOS can not read the data as it can not detect the media. Try recreating it and if the issue persists try a different USB drive if you can, as some can have different types of on board hubs which your BIOS may not support.

Answer (score 0):

Re-create the USB installer with YUMI:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

And try again.

BTW Ubuntu 13.10 is about of getting without support, I'll go with Ubuntu 12.04.4 (going to be released tomorrow) or Ubuntu 12.04.1 for this old laptop. With YUMI you can create a bootable USB stick with the three options (Ubuntu 13.10, 12.04.4 and 12.04.1).